# Using CURL to upload to Dropbox and overwrite a file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, dropbox

I'm a small time admin and would say entry level to Linux. I am trying to use CURL to upload to Dropbox a small backup sqlitedb and have had success for the first upload, however, I am trying to accomplish uploading a file to Dropbox every 30 minutes and overwriting the current file in DROPBOX with the new file from my Linux server (as a jerry-rigged offsite backup of my Teamspeak database)

This is the code I have so far :

```
curl -X PUT https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <dropbox code here>" \
--header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/home/ec2-user/ts3server.sqlitedb.bz2\"}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
--data-binary ts3server.sqlitedb.bz2
```

After running that code once, it doesn't OVERRIDE the current file in my Dropbox account with the updated file. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `mode` with parameter `overwrite`. The default is `add`.

> **Add** - Do not overwrite an existing file if there is a conflict. The autorename strategy is to append a number to the file name. For
>   example, "document.txt" might become "document (2).txt".
>
> **overwrite** - Always overwrite the existing file. The autorename strategy is the same as it is for add.

Reference: [/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload)

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer " \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/Homework/math/Matrices.txt\",\"mode\": \"overwrite\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --data-binary @local_file.txt
```

Comment: I now get an error : 

    code'Warning: Couldn't read data from file "ts3server.sqlitedb.bz2", 
    this makes an
    Warning: empty POST.